# Continuing effectiveness of anti-viral drugs after shingles outbreak

Tags: medications, shingles, antivirals

When shingles is treated with [famciclovir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famciclovir) for a few weeks and the rash disappears but the pain persists, can another course of treatment with [famciclovir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famciclovir) reduce pain? If not, what other medications could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In, shingles, pain commonly persists after rash disappearance and usually disappears on its own. If the pain lasts for more than 30-90 days after rash disappearance, it is called postherpetic neuralgia (PHP).

Antivirals, such as acyclovir, famciclovir and valcyclovir, do not help in postherpetic neuralgia.

[Postherpetic neuralgia, NEJM](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMcp1403062):

> Antiviral drugs are not effective in relieving postherpetic neuralgia.

[Acyclovir for treatment of postherpetic neuralgia: efficacy and pharmacokinetics. (PubMed)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11557467):

> We concluded that **56 days of intravenous and oral acyclovir
>   therapy** were well tolerated but **had little or no effect on the
>   clinical course of postherpetic neuralgia.**

Other drugs, such as anticonvulsants (gabapentin, pregabalin), opioids, tricyclic antidepressants (amitriptyline), capsaicin cream, topical anesthetics (lidocaine) or steroid injections (in chronic cases), may reduce pain. ([UpToDate](https://www.uptodate.com/contents/shingles-beyond-the-basics)) These drugs are usually only mildly to moderately effective.